# Memory Allocation for union

Tags: c, unions

In the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    union a {
        int i;
        char ch[2];
    };
    union a u;
    int b;
    u.ch[0] = 3;
    u.ch[1] = 2;
    printf("%d,%d,%d\n", u.ch[0], u.ch[1], u.i);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is

```
3,2,515
```

Can anyone explain me why the value of `i` is `515`?

Comment: 2*256+3=515 and you're working on a little-endian machine and you're lucky?  You could have gotten garbage too, unless `sizeof(int) == 2`.

Comment: Because undefined behavior.

Comment: If you don't assign to `i`, why do you attempt to print it? Besides, Union members should be used one at a time.

Comment: @machine_1, thats not very clear since C99: _If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). This might be a trap representation._

Comment: My machine printed `3,2,666567171` as @JonathanLeffler surmised, but after initialising the `union` with `union a u = { 0 };` it gives the correct `3,2,515`.

Answer (score 4):

```
union a {
        int i;
        char ch[2];
};
union a u; /* initially it contains gargage data */
```

All members of the union shares the common memory. In above case total of 4 bytes gets allocated for `u` because in 4 bytes(MAX memory needed) you can store both `i` and `ch`.

```
                        ch[1]    ch[0]
    ----------------------------------
   |     G  |   G    |   G   |  G    |  => G means garbage/junk data, because u didn't initialized 
    ----------------------------------
                                     u
  MSB                               LSB
```

when statement `u.ch[0] = 3;` executed only `ch[0]` initialized.

```
                  ch[1]    ch[0]
    --------------------------------------
   |     G  |   G    |   G   | 0000 0011 |  => G means garbage/junk data, because u didn't initialized 
    --------------------------------------
                                        u
 MSB                                   LSB
```

And when `u.ch[1] = 2;` executed next 1 bytes gets initialized as

```
                        ch[1]       ch[0]
    ------------------------------------------
   |     G  |   G    | 0000 0010  | 0000 0011 |  => G means garbage/junk data, because u didn't initialized 
    ------------------------------------------
                                              u
 MSB                                        LSB
```

As you can see above out of `4 bytes` only **first 2 bytes** got **initialized**, still remaining 2 bytes are uninitialised so when you are printing `u.i`, its **undefined behaviour**.

If you want expected result then initialize then union variable first as

```
union a u = { 0 }; /* all 4 bytes got initialized at first instance itself, no chance of any junk data */
 u.ch[0] = 3;
 u.ch[1] = 2;
```

Now when you prints `u.i`, it prints data in whole 4 bytes which is `512 + 3 = 515` (In case of little enidian processor)

Comment: Why the specific operation "512 + 3 = 515" takes place?

Comment: @Rajsi is is not a "specific operation" but an **explanation** of the value you see. The processor reads all 4 bytes of `u.i` together. Similary the decimal number 23 means 2^10 + 3^1.

Comment: which `compiler` you are using ? If  `int` is of `2 bytes` & when `printf("%d\n",u.i);` executed it will try to print value in `2 bytes` which is `513`(calculate from LSB to MSB). If `int` is of `4 bytes` and union variable `u` is not initialized then its UB

Comment: It is only UB if the `union` was not initialised to all `0`. Otherwise the same applies: a * 256^3 + b * 256^2 + c * 256^1 + d * 256^0 (apart from consideration of sign).

Comment: Good point about the partial initialization and hence undefined behavior, but displaying memory contents with decreasing adresses is utterly confusing and not needed for the little endian vs big endian discussion

Comment: Note also that initializing the union may not be enough in all cases: if the members appeared in the opposite order, only the first 2 bytes would be initialized to 0.

Comment: Agree with first point @chqrlie but `initializing member of union` which needs max memory will `initialize whole union`, not just `first 2 bytes`.